# Help needed in selecting the right backpack

Tags: backpacks

I wanted to buy a new backpack. I like one particular one (mainly due to the price) but the problem is i do not know that will i be able to tie my sleeping bag  or sleeping mat to its bottom. I know most of you would say that the sleeping bag should be stuffed inside the bag and i normally do that with my bigger backpack. Its just better to have an option (with a 50-55L bag) to tie something outside  specially if you have a bag, a mat and a tent. I will attach a picture so you guys know if it is possible to attach something to this one.

Thanks

[image: i am looking for to buy one of these]

Comment: There are way too many factors when considering a pack. Whats your torso length? Weight? Strength level? One thing that worries me about this pack is it doesn't appear to have a hip belt, which is a must have. I think any pack under a $200 price tag, honestly, is there for a reason. These things are expensive. My pack costed me nearly $300.

Comment: What's the question here? And yes, hip belts are a must have, otherwise you get serious problems!

Comment: yep i agree a backpack without a hip belt doesn't make any sense. It has one, just not visible in this picture. Any ways i am going to pass this one. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The bag pictured, a Karrimor Bobcat, for some unexplainable reason has a single anchor point on the underside. Two is common, none is understandable, but one makes no sense- tying your sleeping bag on there would cause it to swing around and twirl, unless you went in for some complicated lashing. In any case, as you noted, it's better to have your bag inside the pack to keep it dry and to make your load more compact. If it doesn't fit, you either want a smaller/more compressible bag or a bigger pack.

My personal philosophy is that if you buy the cheapest product available, what you get is the cheapest product available. Quality is generally going to be lower, especially in less-visible areas, and you'll have the minimum of bells and whistles- including, in this case, attachment points. That's the bargain you strike.

Comment: That could be an Ice Axe loop

Comment: Perhaps, but they're generally intended to do double duty as tiedown points, which is why packs tend to have two. More pertinently, there's no way to fasten the spike end, and in any case, how many people who are are traversing glaciers and snowfields are going to go with a $40 pack?

Comment: You definitely have a point, was just mentioning that its primary purpose was likely for an ice axe or similar. I didn't design the pack, but that's what it seems like. I agree, probably not ideal for mountaineering.

Comment: Thanks @Patrick. You are right about the price thing but i can't stop going for trekking just because i can not afford an expensive backpack :) . Probably will buy a really good one when i have the cash. For now i would look for some other backpack under 100$.

Answer (score 0):

Packs are designed to carry the contents within a certain area.  Extending your gear outside this area will cause you discomfort and will increase wear on the pack.  I've never been able to attach more than a poncho or jacket onto the outside of an internal frame pack - such as this one.  They're simply designed to carry everything on the inside.  I would not attempt to tie a sleeping bag or pad to the bottom of this pack.

If you want to attach extra items to your pack, consider an external frame backpack.  Just be sure the load is balanced and your gear does not extend beyond the edges of the frame.

I prefer an external frame because I can use it during all seasons.  When it's warm, I use a compact 20 degree sleeping bag and everything fits inside.  But during cold weather (October-December), I carry a -40 sleeping bag tied to the top and my tent tied to the bottom of the frame.  I also have kids and have had, when they were little, as many as four sleeping bags tied onto my pack at one time.  Maybe that's why my wife prefers an internal frame backpack :)

Comment: My pack has straps on the bottom specifically designed for carrying a sleeping pad, its a rather popular pack as well. While I partially agree that you should put most things in your pack, many packs have features to carry many things on the exterior.